The power plant of the ark ship in the form of a black hole
I would like to warn you right away that I’m new here and not very proficient in English, so there may be some mistakes in my question.
I am developing a science fiction book where I want to move away from clichés but not be afraid to use bold ideas that are conceptually possible.
The story takes place on an ark spaceship that has a power system based on a black hole, which will provide energy in the form of Hawking radiation. The black hole will lose mass, but part of that mass will be replenished by collecting metallic particles in space using magnetic fields.
In theory, this system would provide me with enough energy for the ship and even more. However, I need this energy for a specific purpose. The ship should have certain "fabricators" that could produce matter from energy. Moreover, these fabricators should:

Be durable enough.
Have the ability to produce matter independently over a long period of time (this feature is the basis for the setting).

I would like to hear the opinions of more expert people in physics about what systems could conceptually serve as such "fabricators," as well as receive constructive criticism regarding the ship's power system. Honestly, I can only roughly speculate about the features and challenges that such power systems might have.
And yes, I understand that I’m essentially asking several questions here, but in my opinion, this is a cohesive system that I would prefer not to break down into separate questions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you've just described Romulan Warbirds from Star Trek. Sorry to get biblical on you, but there's nothing new under the sun - of course, that doesn't specify which sun.

It might be helpful to focus on a single issue that you're having trouble with - a problem to solve. Also, please match the title with the body. We do have that pesky rule about "one single focused question per post", which we stick to. As to explanations, we can perhaps give you E=mc^2 type answers regarding energy to matter conversion, but technobabble is outside our remit.

Your English is fine

Can you give us some idea of numbers here, especially for the expected fabricator output?  Ignoring what the system is, it seems that you are trying to get energy (power generation) and mass (fabricator output) out while putting in a limited amount of mass from scavenged space particles.  If you can supply approximate values for the inputs and outputs then we can at least comment on the power economy of the system, even if the technobabble is out of scope.

Hello @GoodGod1345, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. That first comment from SE's automated Community BOT is a bad sign. Whenever you see it, you should plan to [edit] your post. It means your question has violated SE's basic expectations for good questions. The obvious issues are these: (a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question per post. Your opinion about the cohesiveness of the issue doesn't change the rule. In fact, by broadening it with multiple questions you may invoke the Book Rule, meaning the question is too broad to be suitable for Stack Exchange. ... (*Continued*)

... (b) Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. We can help you solve a problem, we cannot discuss your problems. Questions are obligated to seek a single best answer. (c) This might not seem obvious, but Stack Exchange is not meant to replace an education. Explaining a black-hole engine is giving you an education, not helping you solve a problem. (d) We're lenient with new users, so don't worry about it this first round, but please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand the limits of Stack Exchange. Thanks.

@Escapeddentalpatient. As I recall, the TARDIS is also powered by a singularity at its core.

Also, Hawking Radiation has a small output when the blackhole is stable. Only when it is close to evaporating completely, does it become useable. Not thats this should stop you from using the idea. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/139602/could-black-hole-civilizations-even-exist/261941#261941
